# What public.init does in the below code

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and trying to understand what the below code does. Didnt understand why public object was created and then what does public.init do?

Entire code is located at http://jsfiddle.net/UqV4g/43/

```
var geoLocateAddress = function () {
var public = {};

public.init = function() {
    public.initEventHandlers();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public is an object, and `public.init = function...` this code creates new member in `public` object, a function, so later you can use `public.init();` to use that function.

Comment: Couldn't it have started directly from this line `$("#findMyLocation").click(function() {` why did we need the public ojbect

Comment: I have not checked your code on fiddle, but `$("#findMyLocation").click(...` this will trigger only when we click, in some cases like when you are making photo gallery then you need to do some other processes like move to next photo, or view right photo, etc, that time you need to have a method to keep trace of state of object, in that case you have to use the code like you have shown in your question, and code like `$("#findMyLocation").click(..` will be state less, or if you want to keep state track then you have to do some logic manually for it.

Comment: This URL http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-develop-a-jquery-plugin/ will  give you some idea about it.